# Zend Framework - DbAdapter Issue

Tags: zend-framework

I am adapting my Zend Framework to work with phpass as according to: http://jonathanstreet.com/blog/adding-phpass-to-zend-framework/

Following his steps, i encountered this error with his Acai_Auth_Adapter_DbTable:

```
Exception information:

Message: No entry is registered for key 'DbAdapter'
```

How do i resolve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your database adapter is setup in your application.ini similar to:

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.username = "music"
resources.db.params.password = "music"
resources.db.params.dbname = "music"    
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true // add this line to make this adapter default, important if using more then one adapter.
```

in your bootstrap.php you can create a new method similar to:

```
 protected function _initDbAdapter() {//can be named anything as long as it starts with _init
        $db = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions('db'));//get all db adapter resources
        Zend_Registry::set('DbAdapter', $db); //save to Zend_registry key DbAdapter
    }
```

ByteNudger is correct on how use the registry:
`$authAdapter = new Acai_Auth_Adapter_DbTable( $dbAdpater );`

However there is a way to avoid all this bootstrap business. If you are only using one database adapter try:

```
//This will pass in the currently default adapter, if you only have one adapter...
$authAdapter = new Acai_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(Zend_Db::getDefaultAdapter);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the database adapter, which the class `Acai_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` should use by storing a database adapter in `Zend_Registry` with the key `DbAdapter`. The best place to do that is your `Bootstrap.php`:

```
protected function _initDb()
{
  // add code to create a `Zend_Db_Adapter_xxx`
  Zend_Registry::set('DbAdapter') = $dbAdapter;
}
```

How to set up the database adapter you find under [Zend Framework: Documentation: Zend_Db_Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.connecting).

Another way is to pass the database adapter as parameter:

```
// create a database adapter
$authAdapter = new Acai_Auth_Adapter_DbTable( $dbAdpater ):
```

I would recommend the first way, because then you can access your database adapter anywhere in your application with `Zend_Registry::get('DbAdapter')`.